Local homology groups of set of points with integer points
Let $X_1, X_2, X_3 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with at least $i$ integer coordinates, with $i \in \{1,2,3\}$, so $X_3 \subset X_2 \subset X_1$.
I am interested in computing the local homology groups $H_2(X_1, X_1 \setminus\{x\})$ for each $x \in X_1$, and that any homeomorphism of $X_1$ to itself preserves $X_2, X_3$.
I a bit stuck and not even sure where to start.

Start by drawing a picture.

I tried - $X_1$ seems to be the union of "sheets" on each axis, and $X_3$ seems to be a discrete grid; but I still don't see how it helps. Thanks for the comment.

Until you figure out what $X_1$ really is, you cannot solve this problem. Maybe as a warm-up you should solve this problem for similar subsets of $\mathbb R^2$.

in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $X_1$ will be union of lines, $x = n$ and $y=m$ for $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$. I think a similar reasoning leads to what I wrote for the case of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Where is my mistake here? Thanks again

You are right in the $\mathbb R^2$ case, but your description in the $\mathbb R^3$ case is quite vague. Notice that $X_1$ has large group of symmetries which will help you to describe it and to reduce computation of local homology to few special cases.

Let me be more clear about $\mathbb{R}^3$. $X_1$ is the union of hyperplanes $z = n$, $x = m$ and $y = k$, for $n,m,k \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is still not entirely clear to me how to compute the local homologies

Good. Now, for each point $p\in X_3$ take a small sphere centered at $p$ and intersect it with $X_1$. The result is a graph $G_p$. Compute $H_1(G_p)$. Do the same for points $p\in X_2\setminus X_3$ and $p\in X_1\setminus X_2$. Use this computation to compute $H_2(X_1, X_1\setminus p)$ arguing by analogy with computation of local homology of $\mathbb R^n$.
